# Как добавить в статью форму opencart 3?

Tags: opencart

Как добавить в статью форму opencart 3?

Comment: Конкретней пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже решено.
Вводить в текстовый редактор forma
А во фронте заменять тэг, тогда тэг forma не обрезается

```
$('forma').replaceWith( function() { return $( this 
).get(0).outerHTML.replace(/<(\/?)forma/g,'<$1form');} );
```